# Authentication failed - System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception

I'm trying to make simple Ajax request with following code in `main.js` file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SaveStyles.aspx/GetDate",
    data: { someParameter: "some value" },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

In C# in `SaveStyles.aspx.cs` I have method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetDate(string someParameter)
{
    return "Sup!";
}
```

But in JS console I see error saying that authentication is failed with `System.InvalidOperationException`. I have no idea why it's happening. Mabye I shoud add something like `anti-csrf` token?

Answer (score 3):

Resolved by setting AutoDirectMode to Off in App_Start/RouteConfig.cs

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

and adding a ScriptManager to the aspx page that has an EnablePageMethods set to 'true':

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Oh my gosh.  I didn't understand why changing App_Start AutoRedirectMode.  I just did and my problem is resolved.  Thank you SOOO much for providing this solution.